# Windows Service - Config File - install check for changes of that config file

Tags: .net, service, installation

I have a windows service that has a config file. That config file will be changeable by the user.

When I change the code and have to re-install the service the config file will be overwritten.

What I don't want to happen is the end-user gets the config file all configured the way they want, me make code changes, build the installer, run the installer and the customized config file gets ***squashed***.

**Does somebody know of a way that I can compare the config file, in the installer, against the already installed config file?**

Answer (score 0):

What installer technology are you using? Wix? Installshield? Something else? It's probably hard to do from an installer to be honest. We have a similar issue when updating user settings files. For this, we wrote a custom xml parser application that preserved "new" sections and only updated the bits it needed to update. We packed both the installer and the new exe we wrote in a chaining application and ran them one after the other internally. To the user, they are still only running one installer, but internally it's running an installer and a utility for updating a config file.

Not sure if this helps in your situation, but it's certainly one approach you could take.

Comment: Visual Studio Deployment Project and ProjectInstaller class in my project